# Get Nth element from binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

So, logically I see how this would work, however, I can't find working Haskell syntax to express the logic. Here is my attempt with nested guards, which apparently is not a supported feature:

```
data Tree a where
  Nil :: Tree a
  Node :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a

-- Get the nth top element of a sorted binary tree:
getNthElement :: Int -> Tree a -> Either Int a
getNthElement _ Nil = Left 0
getNthElement n (Node l v r)
  | (Right x) <- rightRecurse = rightRecurse
  | (Left nr) <- rightRecurse, nr == n = Right v
  | (Left nr) <- rightRecurse
    | (Right x) <- leftRecurse = leftRecurse
    | (Left nl) <- leftRecurse = Left $ nl + nr + 1
    where leftRecurse = getNthElement (n-nr-1) l in
  where rightRecurse = getNthElement n r
```

Comment: Guards are only valid on function definitions, I would recommend using a case expression instead.  Guards are nice syntax for defining functions, case is a normal expression that can be embedded inside of other expressions.

Comment: perfect! Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: should I delete or wait for someone to give an answer to accept?

Comment: I can post my comment as an answer, but you really did all the work

Comment: go ahead, I will accept and close this thread :)

Comment: @clay It's considered perfectly fine to answer your own question (and generally is considered *better* than putting the answer into the question as an edit, for the obvious metadata correctness reasons).

Comment: ok, I created an answer, but the site says I can't accept it for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bheklilr, a case expression resolved this issue. The working code is:

```
getNthElement :: Int -> Tree a -> Either Int a
getNthElement _ Nil = Left 0
getNthElement n (Node l v r) = case getNthElement n r of
  (Right x) -> (Right x)
  (Left nr) -> if nr == n then Right v
               else case getNthElement (n-nr-1) l of
                    (Right x) -> (Right x)
                    (Left nl) -> Left $ nl + nr + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it (I have put everything in a [self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/529b4772905063e12a85) in case you want to play with it). The `State Int` monad handles the threading of the counter, the `Maybe` alternative picks the right value. I think that the algorithm is more readable this way.

We start with a bunch of imports and your definition of `Tree`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module NthElement where

import Data.Functor
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data Tree a where
  Nil :: Tree a
  Node :: Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

Then we arrive at the main definition: `getNthElement` runs the stateful computation and if we got `Nothing` back, it puts the number of visited nodes (original number minus the final `Int` state), otherwise it gives back the value it found.

```
getNthElement :: Int -> Tree a -> Either Int a
getNthElement k t = maybe (Left $ k - s) Right mv where

  (mv , s) = go t `runState` k

  go :: Tree a -> State Int (Maybe a)
```

The stateful computation itself is a direct translation of your high-level description of the algorithm:

- If we find a `Nil`, there is no value to return (so we fail)

  ```
  go Nil          = return Nothing
  ```
- If we find a `Node` then the nth value we are looking for is either in the right subtree, or in the middle if the counter is `0` after exploring the right subtree, or somewhere in the left subtree:

  ```
  go (Node l v r) = do
    rv <- go r
    k  <- get
    () <- put $ k - 1
    lv <- go l
    return $ rv <|> (v <$ guard (k == 0)) <|> lv
  ```

With this definition it's not immediately clear that we are never doing work that is not needed (we do write `lv <- go l` when it might be the case that the value was already found!). However lazyness is on our side and to convince ourselves that it is indeed ok, we can define a left-infinite tree and observe that `getNthElement` always returns a value:

```
leftInfTree :: Tree Int
leftInfTree = foldr (\ k ih -> Node ih k Nil) Nil [1..]
```

Test in ghci:

```
*NthElement> getNthElement 10 leftInfTree 
Right 11
```

Comment: I tried this out, it completely works, but it seems much more complicated with state monads, do notation, and Applicative operators. The version I posted uses zero extra libraries or type classes, it's smaller and intuitive.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, I suppose. I feel like this presentation is a bit easier for me to understand: the `(Right x) -> (Right x)` branches in your code scream `Alternative` to me.